# Strange thin fonts in Google Chrome last version

Tags: google-chrome

When I rebooted my Mac, Google Chrome suddenly are displaying all fonts in a very thin partly jagged style which wasn´t the case before the reboot.

Is there a way to use CSS to restore it? Is there a known font issue with Chrome?

Chrome version: 18.0.1025.142 Mac OS version: 10.7.2

Thankful for all input!

Comment: I see the barely legible version of Helvetica in Chrome 52 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

There have been problems with the GPU powered font rendering in the dev build of Chrome 18: [gdipp Issue 205](http://code.google.com/p/gdipp/issues/detail?id=205)

The workaround posted there might work for you:

> 1. load chrome://flags/
> 2. disable GPU compositing on all pages, Composited render layer borders, GPU Accelerated Drawing
> 3. relaunch Chrome

You might also try to downgrade Chrome using [one of the versions from here](http://www.oldversion.com/Google-Chrome.html), but you'll have to disable auto-updates to prevent Chrome updating itself back to 18 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The flag solution [has been removed in Chrome 52.](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/06/06/chrome-font-rendering-google/)

Uninstalling the "Roboto Thin" font was the only solution for my Chrome 53. Save and run as `remove_buggy_chrome_font.reg`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Roboto Thin (TrueType)"=-"Roboto-Thin.ttf"
```

Chrome will then use the regular Roboto for extensions like [SessionBuddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko?hl=en) and pages like [Democracy Now!](http://www.democracynow.org/).